# Deb file from sh script

Tags: bash, makefile, packaging, deb

Im trying to establish if it possible to create a deb package for the following app:

http://openfoam.org/download/4-0-source/

It uses an Allmake shell script which contains various standard shell commands and wmake commands to compile the source.  wmake appears to be specific to this application but does call make:

http://www.cfdsupport.com/OpenFOAM-Training-by-CFD-Support/node25.html
https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.1.x/blob/master/wmake/wmake

Is it possible to call the shell script from within a debian/rules file? or is there a better way of doing this if it is indeed possible?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the general idea of the `debian/rules` file is to run whatever commands are required to configure and install the upstream package into a location suitable for the `dpkg` toolchain.

Modern `debhelper`-based `debian/rules` files are typically extremely terse, because most typical packages adhere to build conventions for which good, very simple canned helpers are available, but traditional, more complex and explicit  `rules` files are well-documented in older Debian packaging documentation.

Basically, the `debian/rules` file is a Makefile; it should have a `binary` target with the commands to build the upstream package into the Debian package root.

https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#rules is probably useful as a starting point - unless your needs are really arcane, the `dh` defaults will mostly make sense, and it allows you to easily override the parts which don't.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I wasnt sure if this was going to be possible at all and its my first attempt at packaging, managed to get the script to execute in override_dh_auto_build followed by the bash command.